# Altair's selection and transform_filter via binding_range slider for datetime values doesn't seem to work with equality condition or selector itself

Tags: python-3.x, altair, vega-lite

I wanted to bind a range slider with datetime values to filter a chart for data for a particular date only. Using the **stocks** data, what I want to do is have the x-axis show the companies and y-axis the price of the stocks for a particular day which the user selects via a range slider.

Based on inputs from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62046930/altair-adding-date-slider-for-interactive-scatter-chart-pot) and this [issue](https://github.com/altair-viz/altair/issues/2008) I have the following code which shows something
when the slider is moved around after one particular value (with the inequality condition in `transform_filter`), but is empty for the rest.
What is peculiar is that if I have inequality operator then at least it shows something, but **everything is empty when its `==`**.

```py
import altair as alt
from vega_datasets import data

source = data.stocks()

def timestamp(t):
  return pd.to_datetime(t).timestamp()

slider = alt.binding_range(step=86400, min=timestamp(min(source['date'])), max=timestamp(max(source['date']))) #86400 is the difference b/w consequetive days

select_date = alt.selection_single(fields=['date'], bind=slider, init={'date': timestamp(min(source['date']))})

alt.Chart(source).mark_bar().encode(
    x='symbol',
    y='price',
).add_selection(select_date).transform_filter(alt.datum.date == select_date.date)
```

Since the output is empty I am inclined to conclude that it's the `transform_filter` that is causing issues, but I have been at it for more than 6 hours now and tried all the permutation and combinations of using `alt.expr.toDate` and other conversions here and there but I cannot get it to work.

Also tried just `transform_filter(select_date.date)` and `transform_filter(date)` along with other things but nothing quite works.

The **expected output** is that, the **heights of bars change(due to data being filtered on date) as the user drags the slider**.

Any help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several issues here:

- In Vega-Lite, timestamps are expressed in milliseconds, not seconds
- You are filtering on equality between a numerical timestamp and a string representation of a date.
- Even if you parse the date in the filter expression, Python date parsing and Javascript date parsing behave differently and the results will generally not match. Even within javascript, the date parsing behavior can vary from browser to browser; all this means that filtering on equality of a Python and Javascript timestamp is generally problematic
- The data you are using has monthly timestamps, so the slider step should account for this

Keeping all that in mind, the best course would probably be to adjust the slider values and filter on matching year and month, rather than trying to achieve equality in the exact timestamp. The result looks like this:

```
import altair as alt
from vega_datasets import data
import pandas as pd

source = data.stocks()

def timestamp(t):
  return pd.to_datetime(t).timestamp() * 1000

slider = alt.binding_range(
    step=30 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000, # 30 days in milliseconds
    min=timestamp(min(source['date'])),
    max=timestamp(max(source['date'])))

select_date = alt.selection_single(
    fields=['date'],
    bind=slider,
    init={'date': timestamp(min(source['date']))},
    name='slider')

alt.Chart(source).mark_bar().encode(
    x='symbol',
    y='price',
).add_selection(select_date).transform_filter(
    "(year(datum.date) == year(slider.date[0])) && "
    "(month(datum.date) == month(slider.date[0]))"
)
```

You can view the result here: [vega editor](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-lite/N4IgJghgLhIFygK4CcA29zQgegM5QHsBjAa1wDojcA3EAXwBoQBbCZEjAIzZCYFMAdkQJgAlgIDm8UAA9pIKAE8ADnwwCCzcRHRMAZqL6owGXIuacC6RiEXylqjAEdEEAVFEwP1NfsPGMZWRRIjU6G1wjPiIPAgF5XFRRMD5kexU1OBBccQlUXxADIzBceABtTCg1AF0mTnETBBBxZUQoDGQ3CQLWOTgARgAmADYAdgAWAAZ+4cm5uaYteLgATnGVwdHhgA55heyq5XhBgFYNvbmbcU95SCr4NY2t3b3wmyhOgVw9AmRmctABlQVTSWQAFIo+GwwXdEMxyHc+ABKAAEAF40SjIdDEslUgjoHwypNqkjUQAyckosHMOJQAAWMOgcIJVVRGJRtPcjNxKWQrKJJLJ9GqdCAA).

Comment: This really helps! However, would you be so kind to tell me, how did you know that I need to use `slider.date[0]` instead of `slider.date` or `slider`. I mean in the example from the docs that you modified for datetime x-axis in one of your earlier answers, using `[0]` is not necessary (I checked). At that time I didn't question your approach. But in my case this is precisely what makes the chart work. Could you please tell me how did you figure out about using `[0]` because I haven't come across it in the docs & as someone not familiar with internals, how can I figure it out myself next time?

Comment: `selection.field` returns a list of selected fields - you can see this by opening your chart in the vega editor and clicking on the data tab. The `[0]` is not necessary when using `==` comparisons, because javascript equality does type coercion for you (similar to how `1 == "1"` will return true)