# Trying to run additive transform_filter operations depending on separate interval selection endpoints in altair / vega-lite

Tags: python, altair, vega-lite

**TL;DR:

It seems to me that the problem must be in the way I am trying to get the endpoints from the selections: `(isDefined(brush1.y) ? (brush1.y[0]) : 1)`**

I work with data of sizes of particles of two classes (A and B) from n samples. I want to scatter-plot A against B as the percentages of particles that are within any possible size sub-range.

For interactively selecting these size sub-ranges, I use two auxiliary plots (one for each class) where I added interval selections in order to set and move around the desired ranges.

[image: current state of the chart: scatter point not don't react to selection]

From another question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68485636/using-interval-selection-manipulate-what-is-taken-into-aggregation-of-individua) I already learned that aggregation operations can not be updated by interval selections (which is a [vega-lite issue](https://github.com/vega/vega-lite/pull/7442)). So I prepared my dataframe to contain pre-calculated percentage values for any possible size bin and any possible combination of size bins of A and B. Now, I *"only"* need to find a way to filter this extended dataset down to what is currently selected in the auxiliary plots.

**Example of the dataframe structure:**

```
      sample      A     lower_A    upper_A       B      lower_B     upper_B

 0      S3      20.1         0       100       97.7         0         100
 1      S3      20.1         0       100        0.9       100         200
...    ...       ...       ...       ...        ...       ...         ...
673     S2       6.0       300       500        2.5       200         500
674     S2       6.0       300       500        0.9       300         500
```

The code is using a `transform_calculate` to get the endpoints of the selection (inspired from [here](https://github.com/altair-viz/altair/issues/1765)) and a `transform_filter` to use the extracted values to filter the dataset on the columns representing the upper and lower size boundaries of the percentages of A and B (inspired from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63707521/altairs-selection-and-transform-filter-via-binding-range-slider-for-datetime-va)).

To prevent empty selections from the filtering when interval boundaries are not at values which exist in the dataset (the lower and upper size limits are discrete at 0, 100, 200, 300, 400 and 500), the calculated endpoints are fix to the next full hundred by `ceil()` or `floor()`, [as it was suggested below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69092564/10381546). However, the points that get plotted seem not to react to what intervals are selected. In the data view of the vega-lite editor, I can see that the rows that result from the filtering are always fixed at `lower_` 0 and `upper_` 100, independent of what is selected.

*Example including a working toy dataframe:*

```py
import pandas as pd
import altair as alt


df = pd.DataFrame({'sample':['S3','S3','S3','S3','S3','S3','S3','S3','S3','S3','S3','S3','S3','S3','S3','S1','S1','S1','S1','S1','S1','S1','S1','S1','S1','S1','S1','S1','S1','S1','S2','S2','S2','S2','S2','S2','S2','S2','S2','S2','S2','S2','S2','S2','S2','S3','S3','S3','S3','S3','S3','S3','S3','S3','S3','S3','S3','S3','S3','S3','S1','S1','S1','S1','S1','S1','S1','S1','S1','S1','S1','S1','S1','S1','S1','S2','S2','S2','S2','S2','S2','S2','S2','S2','S2','S2','S2','S2','S2','S2','S3','S3','S3','S3','S3','S3','S3','S3','S3','S3','S3','S3','S3','S3','S3','S1','S1','S1','S1','S1','S1','S1','S1','S1','S1','S1','S1','S1','S1','S1','S2','S2','S2','S2','S2','S2','S2','S2','S2','S2','S2','S2','S2','S2','S2','S3','S3','S3','S3','S3','S3','S3','S3','S3','S3','S3','S3','S3','S3','S3','S1','S1','S1','S1','S1','S1','S1','S1','S1','S1','S1','S1','S1','S1','S1','S2','S2','S2','S2','S2','S2','S2','S2','S2','S2','S2','S2','S2','S2','S2','S3','S3','S3','S3','S3','S3','S3','S3','S3','S3','S3','S3','S3','S3','S3','S1','S1','S1','S1','S1','S1','S1','S1','S1','S1','S1','S1','S1','S1','S1','S2','S2','S2','S2','S2','S2','S2','S2','S2','S2','S2','S2','S2','S2','S2','S3','S3','S3','S3','S3','S3','S3','S3','S3','S3','S3','S3','S3','S3','S3','S1','S1','S1','S1','S1','S1','S1','S1','S1','S1','S1','S1','S1','S1','S1','S2','S2','S2','S2','S2','S2','S2','S2','S2','S2','S2','S2','S2','S2','S2','S3','S3','S3','S3','S3','S3','S3','S3','S3','S3','S3','S3','S3','S3','S3','S1','S1','S1','S1','S1','S1','S1','S1','S1','S1','S1','S1','S1','S1','S1','S2','S2','S2','S2','S2','S2','S2','S2','S2','S2','S2','S2','S2','S2','S2','S3','S3','S3','S3','S3','S3','S3','S3','S3','S3','S3','S3','S3','S3','S3','S1','S1','S1','S1','S1','S1','S1','S1','S1','S1','S1','S1','S1','S1','S1','S2','S2','S2','S2','S2','S2','S2','S2','S2','S2','S2','S2','S2','S2','S2','S3','S3','S3','S3','S3','S3','S3','S3','S3','S3','S3','S3','S3','S3','S3','S1','S1','S1','S1','S1','S1','S1','S1','S1','S1','S1','S1','S1','S1','S1','S2','S2','S2','S2','S2','S2','S2','S2','S2','S2','S2','S2','S2','S2','S2','S3','S3','S3','S3','S3','S3','S3','S3','S3','S3','S3','S3','S3','S3','S3','S1','S1','S1','S1','S1','S1','S1','S1','S1','S1','S1','S1','S1','S1','S1','S2','S2','S2','S2','S2','S2','S2','S2','S2','S2','S2','S2','S2','S2','S2','S3','S3','S3','S3','S3','S3','S3','S3','S3','S3','S3','S3','S3','S3','S3','S1','S1','S1','S1','S1','S1','S1','S1','S1','S1','S1','S1','S1','S1','S1','S2','S2','S2','S2','S2','S2','S2','S2','S2','S2','S2','S2','S2','S2','S2','S3','S3','S3','S3','S3','S3','S3','S3','S3','S3','S3','S3','S3','S3','S3','S1','S1','S1','S1','S1','S1','S1','S1','S1','S1','S1','S1','S1','S1','S1','S2','S2','S2','S2','S2','S2','S2','S2','S2','S2','S2','S2','S2','S2','S2','S3','S3','S3','S3','S3','S3','S3','S3','S3','S3','S3','S3','S3','S3','S3','S1','S1','S1','S1','S1','S1','S1','S1','S1','S1','S1','S1','S1','S1','S1','S2','S2','S2','S2','S2','S2','S2','S2','S2','S2','S2','S2','S2','S2','S2','S3','S3','S3','S3','S3','S3','S3','S3','S3','S3','S3','S3','S3','S3','S3','S1','S1','S1','S1','S1','S1','S1','S1','S1','S1','S1','S1','S1','S1','S1','S2','S2','S2','S2','S2','S2','S2','S2','S2','S2','S2','S2','S2','S2','S2','S3','S3','S3','S3','S3','S3','S3','S3','S3','S3','S3','S3','S3','S3','S3','S1','S1','S1','S1','S1','S1','S1','S1','S1','S1','S1','S1','S1','S1','S1','S2','S2','S2','S2','S2','S2','S2','S2','S2','S2','S2','S2','S2','S2','S2'],'A':[20.1,20.1,20.1,20.1,20.1,20.1,20.1,20.1,20.1,20.1,20.1,20.1,20.1,20.1,20.1,20.9,20.9,20.9,20.9,20.9,20.9,20.9,20.9,20.9,20.9,20.9,20.9,20.9,20.9,20.9,16.5,16.5,16.5,16.5,16.5,16.5,16.5,16.5,16.5,16.5,16.5,16.5,16.5,16.5,16.5,58.1,58.1,58.1,58.1,58.1,58.1,58.1,58.1,58.1,58.1,58.1,58.1,58.1,58.1,58.1,56.5,56.5,56.5,56.5,56.5,56.5,56.5,56.5,56.5,56.5,56.5,56.5,56.5,56.5,56.5,53.6,53.6,53.6,53.6,53.6,53.6,53.6,53.6,53.6,53.6,53.6,53.6,53.6,53.6,53.6,17.2,17.2,17.2,17.2,17.2,17.2,17.2,17.2,17.2,17.2,17.2,17.2,17.2,17.2,17.2,18.9,18.9,18.9,18.9,18.9,18.9,18.9,18.9,18.9,18.9,18.9,18.9,18.9,18.9,18.9,22.6,22.6,22.6,22.6,22.6,22.6,22.6,22.6,22.6,22.6,22.6,22.6,22.6,22.6,22.6,3.1,3.1,3.1,3.1,3.1,3.1,3.1,3.1,3.1,3.1,3.1,3.1,3.1,3.1,3.1,3.1,3.1,3.1,3.1,3.1,3.1,3.1,3.1,3.1,3.1,3.1,3.1,3.1,3.1,3.1,6.0,6.0,6.0,6.0,6.0,6.0,6.0,6.0,6.0,6.0,6.0,6.0,6.0,6.0,6.0,1.6,1.6,1.6,1.6,1.6,1.6,1.6,1.6,1.6,1.6,1.6,1.6,1.6,1.6,1.6,0.5,0.5,0.5,0.5,0.5,0.5,0.5,0.5,0.5,0.5,0.5,0.5,0.5,0.5,0.5,1.2,1.2,1.2,1.2,1.2,1.2,1.2,1.2,1.2,1.2,1.2,1.2,1.2,1.2,1.2,20.1,20.1,20.1,20.1,20.1,20.1,20.1,20.1,20.1,20.1,20.1,20.1,20.1,20.1,20.1,20.9,20.9,20.9,20.9,20.9,20.9,20.9,20.9,20.9,20.9,20.9,20.9,20.9,20.9,20.9,16.5,16.5,16.5,16.5,16.5,16.5,16.5,16.5,16.5,16.5,16.5,16.5,16.5,16.5,16.5,78.2,78.2,78.2,78.2,78.2,78.2,78.2,78.2,78.2,78.2,78.2,78.2,78.2,78.2,78.2,77.4,77.4,77.4,77.4,77.4,77.4,77.4,77.4,77.4,77.4,77.4,77.4,77.4,77.4,77.4,70.1,70.1,70.1,70.1,70.1,70.1,70.1,70.1,70.1,70.1,70.1,70.1,70.1,70.1,70.1,95.3,95.3,95.3,95.3,95.3,95.3,95.3,95.3,95.3,95.3,95.3,95.3,95.3,95.3,95.3,96.3,96.3,96.3,96.3,96.3,96.3,96.3,96.3,96.3,96.3,96.3,96.3,96.3,96.3,96.3,92.8,92.8,92.8,92.8,92.8,92.8,92.8,92.8,92.8,92.8,92.8,92.8,92.8,92.8,92.8,98.4,98.4,98.4,98.4,98.4,98.4,98.4,98.4,98.4,98.4,98.4,98.4,98.4,98.4,98.4,99.5,99.5,99.5,99.5,99.5,99.5,99.5,99.5,99.5,99.5,99.5,99.5,99.5,99.5,99.5,98.8,98.8,98.8,98.8,98.8,98.8,98.8,98.8,98.8,98.8,98.8,98.8,98.8,98.8,98.8,58.1,58.1,58.1,58.1,58.1,58.1,58.1,58.1,58.1,58.1,58.1,58.1,58.1,58.1,58.1,56.5,56.5,56.5,56.5,56.5,56.5,56.5,56.5,56.5,56.5,56.5,56.5,56.5,56.5,56.5,53.6,53.6,53.6,53.6,53.6,53.6,53.6,53.6,53.6,53.6,53.6,53.6,53.6,53.6,53.6,75.2,75.2,75.2,75.2,75.2,75.2,75.2,75.2,75.2,75.2,75.2,75.2,75.2,75.2,75.2,75.4,75.4,75.4,75.4,75.4,75.4,75.4,75.4,75.4,75.4,75.4,75.4,75.4,75.4,75.4,76.3,76.3,76.3,76.3,76.3,76.3,76.3,76.3,76.3,76.3,76.3,76.3,76.3,76.3,76.3,78.3,78.3,78.3,78.3,78.3,78.3,78.3,78.3,78.3,78.3,78.3,78.3,78.3,78.3,78.3,78.6,78.6,78.6,78.6,78.6,78.6,78.6,78.6,78.6,78.6,78.6,78.6,78.6,78.6,78.6,82.3,82.3,82.3,82.3,82.3,82.3,82.3,82.3,82.3,82.3,82.3,82.3,82.3,82.3,82.3,17.2,17.2,17.2,17.2,17.2,17.2,17.2,17.2,17.2,17.2,17.2,17.2,17.2,17.2,17.2,18.9,18.9,18.9,18.9,18.9,18.9,18.9,18.9,18.9,18.9,18.9,18.9,18.9,18.9,18.9,22.6,22.6,22.6,22.6,22.6,22.6,22.6,22.6,22.6,22.6,22.6,22.6,22.6,22.6,22.6,20.2,20.2,20.2,20.2,20.2,20.2,20.2,20.2,20.2,20.2,20.2,20.2,20.2,20.2,20.2,22.0,22.0,22.0,22.0,22.0,22.0,22.0,22.0,22.0,22.0,22.0,22.0,22.0,22.0,22.0,28.7,28.7,28.7,28.7,28.7,28.7,28.7,28.7,28.7,28.7,28.7,28.7,28.7,28.7,28.7,3.1,3.1,3.1,3.1,3.1,3.1,3.1,3.1,3.1,3.1,3.1,3.1,3.1,3.1,3.1,3.1,3.1,3.1,3.1,3.1,3.1,3.1,3.1,3.1,3.1,3.1,3.1,3.1,3.1,3.1,6.0,6.0,6.0,6.0,6.0,6.0,6.0,6.0,6.0,6.0,6.0,6.0,6.0,6.0,6.0],'lower_A':[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,200,200,200,200,200,200,200,200,200,200,200,200,200,200,200,200,200,200,200,200,200,200,200,200,200,200,200,200,200,200,200,200,200,200,200,200,200,200,200,200,200,200,200,200,200,300,300,300,300,300,300,300,300,300,300,300,300,300,300,300,300,300,300,300,300,300,300,300,300,300,300,300,300,300,300,300,300,300,300,300,300,300,300,300,300,300,300,300,300,300,400,400,400,400,400,400,400,400,400,400,400,400,400,400,400,400,400,400,400,400,400,400,400,400,400,400,400,400,400,400,400,400,400,400,400,400,400,400,400,400,400,400,400,400,400,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,200,200,200,200,200,200,200,200,200,200,200,200,200,200,200,200,200,200,200,200,200,200,200,200,200,200,200,200,200,200,200,200,200,200,200,200,200,200,200,200,200,200,200,200,200,200,200,200,200,200,200,200,200,200,200,200,200,200,200,200,200,200,200,200,200,200,200,200,200,200,200,200,200,200,200,200,200,200,200,200,200,200,200,200,200,200,200,200,200,200,300,300,300,300,300,300,300,300,300,300,300,300,300,300,300,300,300,300,300,300,300,300,300,300,300,300,300,300,300,300,300,300,300,300,300,300,300,300,300,300,300,300,300,300,300],'upper_A':[100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,200,200,200,200,200,200,200,200,200,200,200,200,200,200,200,200,200,200,200,200,200,200,200,200,200,200,200,200,200,200,200,200,200,200,200,200,200,200,200,200,200,200,200,200,200,300,300,300,300,300,300,300,300,300,300,300,300,300,300,300,300,300,300,300,300,300,300,300,300,300,300,300,300,300,300,300,300,300,300,300,300,300,300,300,300,300,300,300,300,300,400,400,400,400,400,400,400,400,400,400,400,400,400,400,400,400,400,400,400,400,400,400,400,400,400,400,400,400,400,400,400,400,400,400,400,400,400,400,400,400,400,400,400,400,400,500,500,500,500,500,500,500,500,500,500,500,500,500,500,500,500,500,500,500,500,500,500,500,500,500,500,500,500,500,500,500,500,500,500,500,500,500,500,500,500,500,500,500,500,500,200,200,200,200,200,200,200,200,200,200,200,200,200,200,200,200,200,200,200,200,200,200,200,200,200,200,200,200,200,200,200,200,200,200,200,200,200,200,200,200,200,200,200,200,200,300,300,300,300,300,300,300,300,300,300,300,300,300,300,300,300,300,300,300,300,300,300,300,300,300,300,300,300,300,300,300,300,300,300,300,300,300,300,300,300,300,300,300,300,300,400,400,400,400,400,400,400,400,400,400,400,400,400,400,400,400,400,400,400,400,400,400,400,400,400,400,400,400,400,400,400,400,400,400,400,400,400,400,400,400,400,400,400,400,400,500,500,500,500,500,500,500,500,500,500,500,500,500,500,500,500,500,500,500,500,500,500,500,500,500,500,500,500,500,500,500,500,500,500,500,500,500,500,500,500,500,500,500,500,500,300,300,300,300,300,300,300,300,300,300,300,300,300,300,300,300,300,300,300,300,300,300,300,300,300,300,300,300,300,300,300,300,300,300,300,300,300,300,300,300,300,300,300,300,300,400,400,400,400,400,400,400,400,400,400,400,400,400,400,400,400,400,400,400,400,400,400,400,400,400,400,400,400,400,400,400,400,400,400,400,400,400,400,400,400,400,400,400,400,400,500,500,500,500,500,500,500,500,500,500,500,500,500,500,500,500,500,500,500,500,500,500,500,500,500,500,500,500,500,500,500,500,500,500,500,500,500,500,500,500,500,500,500,500,500,400,400,400,400,400,400,400,400,400,400,400,400,400,400,400,400,400,400,400,400,400,400,400,400,400,400,400,400,400,400,400,400,400,400,400,400,400,400,400,400,400,400,400,400,400,500,500,500,500,500,500,500,500,500,500,500,500,500,500,500,500,500,500,500,500,500,500,500,500,500,500,500,500,500,500,500,500,500,500,500,500,500,500,500,500,500,500,500,500,500,500,500,500,500,500,500,500,500,500,500,500,500,500,500,500,500,500,500,500,500,500,500,500,500,500,500,500,500,500,500,500,500,500,500,500,500,500,500,500,500,500,500,500,500,500],'B':[97.7,0.9,0.2,0.5,0.4,97.7,98.6,98.8,99.3,0.9,1.1,1.6,0.2,0.6,0.5,91.3,4.7,1.8,1.2,0.6,91.3,96.1,97.9,99.0,4.7,6.5,7.7,1.8,3.0,1.2,90.3,6.5,1.7,0.9,0.4,90.3,96.8,98.5,99.4,6.5,8.2,9.1,1.7,2.5,0.9,97.7,0.9,0.2,0.5,0.4,97.7,98.6,98.8,99.3,0.9,1.1,1.6,0.2,0.6,0.5,91.3,4.7,1.8,1.2,0.6,91.3,96.1,97.9,99.0,4.7,6.5,7.7,1.8,3.0,1.2,90.3,6.5,1.7,0.9,0.4,90.3,96.8,98.5,99.4,6.5,8.2,9.1,1.7,2.5,0.9,97.7,0.9,0.2,0.5,0.4,97.7,98.6,98.8,99.3,0.9,1.1,1.6,0.2,0.6,0.5,91.3,4.7,1.8,1.2,0.6,91.3,96.1,97.9,99.0,4.7,6.5,7.7,1.8,3.0,1.2,90.3,6.5,1.7,0.9,0.4,90.3,96.8,98.5,99.4,6.5,8.2,9.1,1.7,2.5,0.9,97.7,0.9,0.2,0.5,0.4,97.7,98.6,98.8,99.3,0.9,1.1,1.6,0.2,0.6,0.5,91.3,4.7,1.8,1.2,0.6,91.3,96.1,97.9,99.0,4.7,6.5,7.7,1.8,3.0,1.2,90.3,6.5,1.7,0.9,0.4,90.3,96.8,98.5,99.4,6.5,8.2,9.1,1.7,2.5,0.9,97.7,0.9,0.2,0.5,0.4,97.7,98.6,98.8,99.3,0.9,1.1,1.6,0.2,0.6,0.5,91.3,4.7,1.8,1.2,0.6,91.3,96.1,97.9,99.0,4.7,6.5,7.7,1.8,3.0,1.2,90.3,6.5,1.7,0.9,0.4,90.3,96.8,98.5,99.4,6.5,8.2,9.1,1.7,2.5,0.9,97.7,0.9,0.2,0.5,0.4,97.7,98.6,98.8,99.3,0.9,1.1,1.6,0.2,0.6,0.5,91.3,4.7,1.8,1.2,0.6,91.3,96.1,97.9,99.0,4.7,6.5,7.7,1.8,3.0,1.2,90.3,6.5,1.7,0.9,0.4,90.3,96.8,98.5,99.4,6.5,8.2,9.1,1.7,2.5,0.9,97.7,0.9,0.2,0.5,0.4,97.7,98.6,98.8,99.3,0.9,1.1,1.6,0.2,0.6,0.5,91.3,4.7,1.8,1.2,0.6,91.3,96.1,97.9,99.0,4.7,6.5,7.7,1.8,3.0,1.2,90.3,6.5,1.7,0.9,0.4,90.3,96.8,98.5,99.4,6.5,8.2,9.1,1.7,2.5,0.9,97.7,0.9,0.2,0.5,0.4,97.7,98.6,98.8,99.3,0.9,1.1,1.6,0.2,0.6,0.5,91.3,4.7,1.8,1.2,0.6,91.3,96.1,97.9,99.0,4.7,6.5,7.7,1.8,3.0,1.2,90.3,6.5,1.7,0.9,0.4,90.3,96.8,98.5,99.4,6.5,8.2,9.1,1.7,2.5,0.9,97.7,0.9,0.2,0.5,0.4,97.7,98.6,98.8,99.3,0.9,1.1,1.6,0.2,0.6,0.5,91.3,4.7,1.8,1.2,0.6,91.3,96.1,97.9,99.0,4.7,6.5,7.7,1.8,3.0,1.2,90.3,6.5,1.7,0.9,0.4,90.3,96.8,98.5,99.4,6.5,8.2,9.1,1.7,2.5,0.9,97.7,0.9,0.2,0.5,0.4,97.7,98.6,98.8,99.3,0.9,1.1,1.6,0.2,0.6,0.5,91.3,4.7,1.8,1.2,0.6,91.3,96.1,97.9,99.0,4.7,6.5,7.7,1.8,3.0,1.2,90.3,6.5,1.7,0.9,0.4,90.3,96.8,98.5,99.4,6.5,8.2,9.1,1.7,2.5,0.9,97.7,0.9,0.2,0.5,0.4,97.7,98.6,98.8,99.3,0.9,1.1,1.6,0.2,0.6,0.5,91.3,4.7,1.8,1.2,0.6,91.3,96.1,97.9,99.0,4.7,6.5,7.7,1.8,3.0,1.2,90.3,6.5,1.7,0.9,0.4,90.3,96.8,98.5,99.4,6.5,8.2,9.1,1.7,2.5,0.9,97.7,0.9,0.2,0.5,0.4,97.7,98.6,98.8,99.3,0.9,1.1,1.6,0.2,0.6,0.5,91.3,4.7,1.8,1.2,0.6,91.3,96.1,97.9,99.0,4.7,6.5,7.7,1.8,3.0,1.2,90.3,6.5,1.7,0.9,0.4,90.3,96.8,98.5,99.4,6.5,8.2,9.1,1.7,2.5,0.9,97.7,0.9,0.2,0.5,0.4,97.7,98.6,98.8,99.3,0.9,1.1,1.6,0.2,0.6,0.5,91.3,4.7,1.8,1.2,0.6,91.3,96.1,97.9,99.0,4.7,6.5,7.7,1.8,3.0,1.2,90.3,6.5,1.7,0.9,0.4,90.3,96.8,98.5,99.4,6.5,8.2,9.1,1.7,2.5,0.9,97.7,0.9,0.2,0.5,0.4,97.7,98.6,98.8,99.3,0.9,1.1,1.6,0.2,0.6,0.5,91.3,4.7,1.8,1.2,0.6,91.3,96.1,97.9,99.0,4.7,6.5,7.7,1.8,3.0,1.2,90.3,6.5,1.7,0.9,0.4,90.3,96.8,98.5,99.4,6.5,8.2,9.1,1.7,2.5,0.9,97.7,0.9,0.2,0.5,0.4,97.7,98.6,98.8,99.3,0.9,1.1,1.6,0.2,0.6,0.5,91.3,4.7,1.8,1.2,0.6,91.3,96.1,97.9,99.0,4.7,6.5,7.7,1.8,3.0,1.2,90.3,6.5,1.7,0.9,0.4,90.3,96.8,98.5,99.4,6.5,8.2,9.1,1.7,2.5,0.9],'lower_B':[0,100,200,300,400,0,0,0,0,100,100,100,200,200,300,0,100,200,300,400,0,0,0,0,100,100,100,200,200,300,0,100,200,300,400,0,0,0,0,100,100,100,200,200,300,0,100,200,300,400,0,0,0,0,100,100,100,200,200,300,0,100,200,300,400,0,0,0,0,100,100,100,200,200,300,0,100,200,300,400,0,0,0,0,100,100,100,200,200,300,0,100,200,300,400,0,0,0,0,100,100,100,200,200,300,0,100,200,300,400,0,0,0,0,100,100,100,200,200,300,0,100,200,300,400,0,0,0,0,100,100,100,200,200,300,0,100,200,300,400,0,0,0,0,100,100,100,200,200,300,0,100,200,300,400,0,0,0,0,100,100,100,200,200,300,0,100,200,300,400,0,0,0,0,100,100,100,200,200,300,0,100,200,300,400,0,0,0,0,100,100,100,200,200,300,0,100,200,300,400,0,0,0,0,100,100,100,200,200,300,0,100,200,300,400,0,0,0,0,100,100,100,200,200,300,0,100,200,300,400,0,0,0,0,100,100,100,200,200,300,0,100,200,300,400,0,0,0,0,100,100,100,200,200,300,0,100,200,300,400,0,0,0,0,100,100,100,200,200,300,0,100,200,300,400,0,0,0,0,100,100,100,200,200,300,0,100,200,300,400,0,0,0,0,100,100,100,200,200,300,0,100,200,300,400,0,0,0,0,100,100,100,200,200,300,0,100,200,300,400,0,0,0,0,100,100,100,200,200,300,0,100,200,300,400,0,0,0,0,100,100,100,200,200,300,0,100,200,300,400,0,0,0,0,100,100,100,200,200,300,0,100,200,300,400,0,0,0,0,100,100,100,200,200,300,0,100,200,300,400,0,0,0,0,100,100,100,200,200,300,0,100,200,300,400,0,0,0,0,100,100,100,200,200,300,0,100,200,300,400,0,0,0,0,100,100,100,200,200,300,0,100,200,300,400,0,0,0,0,100,100,100,200,200,300,0,100,200,300,400,0,0,0,0,100,100,100,200,200,300,0,100,200,300,400,0,0,0,0,100,100,100,200,200,300,0,100,200,300,400,0,0,0,0,100,100,100,200,200,300,0,100,200,300,400,0,0,0,0,100,100,100,200,200,300,0,100,200,300,400,0,0,0,0,100,100,100,200,200,300,0,100,200,300,400,0,0,0,0,100,100,100,200,200,300,0,100,200,300,400,0,0,0,0,100,100,100,200,200,300,0,100,200,300,400,0,0,0,0,100,100,100,200,200,300,0,100,200,300,400,0,0,0,0,100,100,100,200,200,300,0,100,200,300,400,0,0,0,0,100,100,100,200,200,300,0,100,200,300,400,0,0,0,0,100,100,100,200,200,300,0,100,200,300,400,0,0,0,0,100,100,100,200,200,300,0,100,200,300,400,0,0,0,0,100,100,100,200,200,300,0,100,200,300,400,0,0,0,0,100,100,100,200,200,300,0,100,200,300,400,0,0,0,0,100,100,100,200,200,300,0,100,200,300,400,0,0,0,0,100,100,100,200,200,300],'upper_B':[100,200,300,400,500,200,300,400,500,300,400,500,400,500,500,100,200,300,400,500,200,300,400,500,300,400,500,400,500,500,100,200,300,400,500,200,300,400,500,300,400,500,400,500,500,100,200,300,400,500,200,300,400,500,300,400,500,400,500,500,100,200,300,400,500,200,300,400,500,300,400,500,400,500,500,100,200,300,400,500,200,300,400,500,300,400,500,400,500,500,100,200,300,400,500,200,300,400,500,300,400,500,400,500,500,100,200,300,400,500,200,300,400,500,300,400,500,400,500,500,100,200,300,400,500,200,300,400,500,300,400,500,400,500,500,100,200,300,400,500,200,300,400,500,300,400,500,400,500,500,100,200,300,400,500,200,300,400,500,300,400,500,400,500,500,100,200,300,400,500,200,300,400,500,300,400,500,400,500,500,100,200,300,400,500,200,300,400,500,300,400,500,400,500,500,100,200,300,400,500,200,300,400,500,300,400,500,400,500,500,100,200,300,400,500,200,300,400,500,300,400,500,400,500,500,100,200,300,400,500,200,300,400,500,300,400,500,400,500,500,100,200,300,400,500,200,300,400,500,300,400,500,400,500,500,100,200,300,400,500,200,300,400,500,300,400,500,400,500,500,100,200,300,400,500,200,300,400,500,300,400,500,400,500,500,100,200,300,400,500,200,300,400,500,300,400,500,400,500,500,100,200,300,400,500,200,300,400,500,300,400,500,400,500,500,100,200,300,400,500,200,300,400,500,300,400,500,400,500,500,100,200,300,400,500,200,300,400,500,300,400,500,400,500,500,100,200,300,400,500,200,300,400,500,300,400,500,400,500,500,100,200,300,400,500,200,300,400,500,300,400,500,400,500,500,100,200,300,400,500,200,300,400,500,300,400,500,400,500,500,100,200,300,400,500,200,300,400,500,300,400,500,400,500,500,100,200,300,400,500,200,300,400,500,300,400,500,400,500,500,100,200,300,400,500,200,300,400,500,300,400,500,400,500,500,100,200,300,400,500,200,300,400,500,300,400,500,400,500,500,100,200,300,400,500,200,300,400,500,300,400,500,400,500,500,100,200,300,400,500,200,300,400,500,300,400,500,400,500,500,100,200,300,400,500,200,300,400,500,300,400,500,400,500,500,100,200,300,400,500,200,300,400,500,300,400,500,400,500,500,100,200,300,400,500,200,300,400,500,300,400,500,400,500,500,100,200,300,400,500,200,300,400,500,300,400,500,400,500,500,100,200,300,400,500,200,300,400,500,300,400,500,400,500,500,100,200,300,400,500,200,300,400,500,300,400,500,400,500,500,100,200,300,400,500,200,300,400,500,300,400,500,400,500,500,100,200,300,400,500,200,300,400,500,300,400,500,400,500,500,100,200,300,400,500,200,300,400,500,300,400,500,400,500,500,100,200,300,400,500,200,300,400,500,300,400,500,400,500,500,100,200,300,400,500,200,300,400,500,300,400,500,400,500,500,100,200,300,400,500,200,300,400,500,300,400,500,400,500,500,100,200,300,400,500,200,300,400,500,300,400,500,400,500,500]})


brush1 = alt.selection_interval(name="brush1", encodings=['y'])
brush2 = alt.selection_interval(name="brush2", encodings=['x'])


scatter = alt.Chart(df
).transform_calculate(
    b1l='floor((isDefined(brush1.y) ? (brush1.y[0]) : 1) / 100) * 100',
    b1u='ceil((isDefined(brush1.y) ? (brush1.y[1]) : 1) / 100) * 100',
    b2l='floor((isDefined(brush2.x) ? (brush2.x[0]) : 1) / 100) * 100',
    b2u='ceil((isDefined(brush2.x) ? (brush2.x[1]) : 1) / 100) * 100',
).mark_point().encode(
    x = 'B',
    y = 'A',
    tooltip = 'sample'
).transform_filter(
    '(datum.lower_A == datum.b1l) &&'
    '(datum.upper_A == datum.b1u) &&'
    '(datum.lower_B == datum.b2l) &&'
    '(datum.upper_B == datum.b2u)'
)
    

A = alt.Chart(df).mark_line().encode(
    x = 'mean(A)',
    y = alt.Y('lower_A', axis=alt.Axis(title='Select size range for A'))
).transform_filter(
    '(datum.lower_A == datum.lower_B) &&'
    '(datum.upper_A == datum.upper_B)'
).add_selection(
    brush1
).properties(
    height = 300,
    width = 100
)


B = alt.Chart(df).mark_line().encode(
    x = alt.X('lower_B', axis=alt.Axis(title='Select size range for B')),
    y = 'mean(B)'
).transform_filter(
    '(datum.lower_A == datum.lower_B) &&'
    '(datum.upper_A == datum.upper_B)'
).add_selection(
    brush2
).properties(
    height = 100,
    width = 400
)


A | scatter & B
```

Can someone spot if I am doing something wrong here? Or give hints if I should tackle it in a completely different way?

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue is that you are using `==` equality between a discrete value (`lower_A`, `lower_B`) and a continuous value (the brush extents). It is very hard to land on the *precise* brush extents where all these equalities are met.

You might try using not so stringent a filter, perhaps with `<=` or `>=`, or using the [floor](https://vega.github.io/vega/docs/expressions/#floor) or [ceil](https://vega.github.io/vega/docs/expressions/#ceil) functions within your filter expression.

Comment: Yes, I also thought that might be the culprit (and then I tried setting the intervals to exact numbers I knew existed in the lower_ and upper_ size columns by watching the signal viewer in vega-lite editor). Now I also tried using `>=` and `<=` instead of `==` as you suggest, but it did not bring up any point in the scatter plot either. So that's not the solution yet

Comment: UPDATE: with `floor` and `ceil`, 3 points appear (one per sample, as expected), however, they don't react to the brushes. The editor shows that they always correspond to the rows with values `0` and `100` for `lower_` and `upper_` / `a` and `b`, respectively. This is how I used it:  `).transform_calculate(
    b1l='floor((isDefined(brush1.y) ? (brush1.y[0]) : 1) / 100) * 100',
    b1u='ceil((isDefined(brush1.y) ? (brush1.y[1]) : 1) / 100) * 100',
    b2l='floor((isDefined(brush2.x) ? (brush2.x[0]) : 1) / 100) * 100',
    b2u='ceil((isDefined(brush2.x) ? (brush2.x[1]) : 1) / 100) * 100',`